# Creating array from reading a file

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a file with the following:

> 5
>   212:Float On:Modest Mouse
>   259:Cherub Rock:Smashing Pumpkins
>   512:Won't Get Fooled Again:The Who
>   417:Teen Age Riot:Sonic Youth
>   299:PDA:Interpol

I need to create a array but I need to take into account the integer it starts with, then read the rest as strings taking into account the initial line containing only an integer. I've made the method to read the file and print, just don't know how to split it up.

Comment: "__ but I Need to take into account the integer it starts with__" can you clarify this ?

Comment: For the integer, use `split` function and take the first element and `parse` it.

Comment: the integer "5" at the top is the number of tracks in the file. and also I need to read the rest of the lines as strings but first convert to integer because of the integers they start with

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

An example of how to do it:

```
String s = "212:Float On:Modest Mouse"; // your input - a line from the file

String[] arr = s.split(":");

System.out.println(arr[0]); // your int

// The rest of the array elements will be the remaining text.
// You can concatenate them back into one string if necessary.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read file using Scanner

```
readlines = new Scanner(filename);
while(readlines.hasNextLine())
{
   String  line = readlines.nextLine();
   String[] values = line.split(":");
   int firstColumn = -1;
   if (values.length > 0) {
       try {
           firstColumn = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
       } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
           // the value in the first column is not an integer
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've grown a habit of reading the entire file into a List, then handling the List in memory.  Doing this is not the only option.

Once I have the file read in, I look at the first line to know how many tracks to expect in the remaining file.  I then would loop through the remaining List to either get the number of tracks from the first line or until I reach the end of the list, in the event that the number of tracks (from the first line) exceeds the actual amount of tracks that are in the file.

As I go through the tracks I would use `substring` to break the line apart, and convert just the first part.

### Update

Base on your comment, I've updated to use split instead of substring.  Then some basic alignment formatting for output

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String yourFile = "path to your file.txt";

    List<String> yourFileLines = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(yourFile)));

    // You know the first line is suppose to be the number of tracks so convert it to a number
    int numberOfTracks = Integer.valueOf(yourFileLines.get(0));

    // Either go to the number of tracks or till the end of file
    List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; (i <= numberOfTracks && i < yourFileLines.size()); i++) {
        String currentFileLine = yourFileLines.get(i);
        String[] currentFileLinePieces = currentFileLine.split(":");

        Track currentTrack = new Track();
        currentTrack.TrackTime = Integer.valueOf(currentFileLinePieces[0]);
        currentTrack.TrackTitle = currentFileLinePieces[1];
        currentTrack.TrackArtist = currentFileLinePieces[2];
        tracks.add(currentTrack);
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("%-20s\t\t%-20s\t\t%-20s", "TITLE", "ARTIST", "TIME"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%-20s\t\t%-20s\t\t%-20s", "-----", "------", "----"));
    for (Track currentTrack : tracks) {
        System.out.println(currentTrack);
    }
}

public static class Track {
    public int TrackTime;
    public String TrackTitle;
    public String TrackArtist;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-20s\t\t%-20s\t\t%-20d", TrackTitle, TrackArtist, TrackTime);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Here's an example using a Scanner, and breaking everything into methods.  You should be able to use `List` and `ArrayList`.  Results are the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String yourFile = "data.txt";
    List<String> yourFileLines = readFile(yourFile);

    if (yourFileLines.size() > 0) {
        // You know the first line is suppose to be the number of tracks so convert it to a number
        int numberOfTracks = Integer.valueOf(yourFileLines.get(0));
        List<Track> tracks = getTracks(numberOfTracks, yourFileLines);
        printTracks(tracks);       
    }
}

public static List<String> readFile(String pathToYourFile) {
    List<String> yourFileLines = new ArrayList();

    try {
        File yourFile = new File(pathToYourFile);
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(yourFile);
        while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
            yourFileLines.add(inputFile.nextLine().trim());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return yourFileLines;
}

public static List<Track> getTracks(int numberOfTracks, List<String> yourFileLines) {
    List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList();

    // Either go to the number of tracks or till the end of file
    for (int i = 1; (i <= numberOfTracks && i < yourFileLines.size()); i++) {
        String currentFileLine = yourFileLines.get(i);
        String[] currentFileLinePieces = currentFileLine.split(":");

        Track currentTrack = new Track();
        currentTrack.TrackTime = Integer.valueOf(currentFileLinePieces[0]);
        currentTrack.TrackTitle = currentFileLinePieces[1];
        currentTrack.TrackArtist = currentFileLinePieces[2];
        tracks.add(currentTrack);
    }
    return tracks;
}

public static void printTracks(List<Track> tracks) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%-20s\t\t%-20s\t\t%-20s", "TITLE", "ARTIST", "TIME"));
    System.out.println(String.format("%-20s\t\t%-20s\t\t%-20s", "-----", "------", "----"));
    for (Track currentTrack : tracks) {
        System.out.println(currentTrack);
    }
}

public static class Track {

    public int TrackTime;
    public String TrackTitle;
    public String TrackArtist;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-20s\t\t%-20s\t\t%-20d", TrackTitle, TrackArtist, TrackTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the reading it and printing it. Now I have to take each string and put it under 3 headings of TITLE ARTIST TIME. That's the problem I am really having.

Comment: I think your code is for java compiler 1.7 eclipse is showing errors on some things

Comment: there are red lines under all the "ArrayList" and "Files" and "Paths" in the ----new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(myFile)));

Comment: @James From the documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html, ArrayList are from 1.2.  Files and Paths are from 1.7.  What version are you using?  If you can't upgrade to 1.7, I believe the substitute would be to use a BufferedReader or a Scanner.

Comment: 1.6 it says in preference. Thats what I've been using for this class. I've been using the scanner method a lot with most programs so how could I substitute that? And also break it up into different methods? I really need help on this, this is my last lab of the semester.